# C# UWP buttons not align the way I wanted

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created a button next to my "Start" button. In my xaml page, the button appears at where I want it to be.

[image]

However, when I run the app, it appears at a random location.

[image]

how do I fix this ?

```
StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Description:" Style="{StaticResource SampleHeaderTextStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ScenarioDescriptionTextStyle}" Text="This page is where your exercise starts " FontSize="20"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="20">
            Follow the instruction and press "Start" to begin the exercise.
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="15">
            (Ensure the connected BLE device is working before starting the exercise.)
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtClock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="20"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="38" Width="106" Click="btnStart_Click_1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtExercise"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="15"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtAngle"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="15"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtDisplay"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtAgain" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="15"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRefresh" Content="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="38" Width="106" Margin="150,-158,0,0" Click="btnRefresh_Click"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide the xaml/c# code you use to create the buttons?

Comment: I edited my post. Is that what you were referring to ?

Comment: @Okay best to post complete page xaml, so we can see what can be done to better it. The margin on your btnRefresh seems very strange at least, guessing you 'drag & dropped' the elements onto the designer?

Comment: ya I drag and copied it

Comment: is this enough information ? @Depechie

Comment: Yes, but Daniel his answer on better to use a Grid is the solution to go for.

Comment: I think Grid will perfectly solve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `Margin-Property` of the button it makes sense that it will pop up somewhere else.

To be honest I don't really know why but I had the same problems.

I would advise you to either use a `RelativePanel` a `StackPanel` or a `Grid`.

You can have a read on [this microsoft page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels) To find out more about the difference between the various types.

A grid would look something like this:
(Keep in mind a grid is 0 indexed)

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="100"/> //For a Row of 100 units height
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/> //For a Row which fills the rest of the available screen space
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/> //For a column of 100 units width
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> //For a column which fills the rest of the screen
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Button x:Name="Button1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
  <Button x:Name="Button2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

A Stackpanel would look like this:
(A thing to keep in mind here is that a Stackpanel will not resize its elements when the screen/window size changes)

```
<Stackpanel Orientation="horizontal">
  <Button x:Name="Button1"/>
  <Button x:Name="Button2"/>
</Stackpanel>
```

Comment: When you copy it like I wrote it then you would need to remove the comments from the code. But when I do that it works. You just need to add the other properties like `width` or `hight` or `content` to the buttons. I just wanted to show you how to use the grid/Stackpanel.